# C++: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I tested with lists in C++ and created a simpliest class for it. I removed some checks and other methods to show only the important points.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.00)
PROJECT(test)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test main.cpp CList.h)
```

**CList.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CLIST_H
#define CLIST_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdint.h>

struct CItem {
    size_t data;
    CItem *prev;
    CItem *next;

    CItem(size_t item);

    ~CItem();
};

CItem::CItem(size_t item) {
    this->data = item;
    this->prev = NULL;
    this->next = NULL;
}

CItem::~CItem() {
    delete this->next;
}

class CList {
    CItem *first;
    CItem *last;
    size_t length;
public:
    CList();

    ~CList();

    CList &add(size_t data);
};

CList::CList() {
    this->first = NULL;
    this->last = NULL;
    this->length = 0;
}

CList::~CList() {
    delete this->first;
}

CList &CList::add(size_t data) {
    CItem *item = new CItem(data);
    if (!item) {
        fputs("Not enough memory", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!this->length) {
        this->first = this->last = item;
    } else {
        item->prev = this->last;
        this->last->next = item;
        this->last = this->last->next;
    }
    this->length++;

    return *this;
}

#endif //CLIST_H
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "CList.h"

int main() {
    CList list;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the CList destructor calls the CItem destructor of the first item, which called other items destructor in recursion.

To test the code, I added 1,000,000 items to the list. Code should free memory on exist. But I'm getting the SIGSEGV error on the CItem destructor (not on the first item).
When I added only 100,000 items there was no error. The error appears with a large numbers of elements.

Again, that is not a real code, just some tests. I know I can use at least the `std::` classes instead. I tried to do this as simple as possible using native types.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code that much but it might be that you ended up with lack of memory issue.

Comment: What the lack of memory issue? There are destructors for free memory. Or they work other way I expect?

Comment: Yes, destructors are called once the program has finished but, if you try to allocate too many items in the list, then you can experience lack of memory issue (there is no that much memory on the system).

Comment: I haven’t been able to run your code as I’m on mobile. But in your destructor chain you don’t set next back to NULL, or check if it is not NULL before deleting. It’s possible that something is destructed (leaving a dangling pointer) then attempted to destruct again as process exits

Comment: @Kieran, Deleting a null pointer is a no-op. Better to be able to find out through a tool complaining about the double delete than to have it silently do nothing.

Comment: Yes, I meant that as the pointer is left dangling a double delete would be unsafe as oppose to delete on NULL and could be causing thrown error. Although I realise now it seems to matter how many were created so this seems unlikely to be the reason

Comment: @Kieran setting pointers to null in a destructor just shifts the undefined behaviour further down the line, calling a destructor twice will cause errors, working around it by nulling member variables is not the right approach

Comment: of course. I’m not what I was thinking now with my original comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates a stack overflow because it recursively deletes the next node from the destructor of the previous one. When you have a million elements this results in a million recursions. Stack size is limited to around 1-8MB on most platforms which even if each function call only used 8 bytes of stack (generally it'd be more) would cause an overflow for a million elements.

You should non-recursively delete the items in the `CList` destructor:

```
CList::~CList() {
    CItem* item = this->first;
    while (item) {
        CItem* temp = item;
        item = item->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the point in recursion... I understood you. It was beatuful when the list need to detele only the first item and other items will be deleted by previous ones without controll from the list.